# Convention when considering a mathematical pendulum attached to an object with a spring

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, potential-energy, conventions, spring

[image]

Sorry for the horrible picture, it was the best I could do.
I am trying to find the lagrangian for this set up, but I have problem with the convention of the potential energy, whether it should be negative or positive, since our system is below the x-axis.

So we have:

object with mass m1.

object with mass m2.

weightless spring with spring const. k1.

rod with length l2, weightless.

$\phi_1(t)$ is the angle between the y-axis and m1.$\phi_2(t)$ is the angle between the vertical axis and m2.

Now:

$\vec r_1(t)=l_f(t)[sin(\phi_1(t)),-cos(\phi_1(t))]$

$\vec r_2(t)=[l_f(t)sin(\phi_1(t))+l_2sin(\phi_2(t)),-l_f(t)cos(\phi_1(t))-l_2cos(\phi_2(t))]$

Now I am trying to find the lagrangian, but the only problem I have, is that I am not sure about the sign of the potential energy. It should be positive, but at the same time, we are below the x-axis. Anyway this is what i tried to do:

For m1:

$U_{m1}=\frac 1 2 k_1 \vec r_1(t)^2 $

$T_{m1}=\frac 1 2 m_1 \dot{\vec r_1(t)}^2$

For m2:

$T_{m2}=\frac 1 2 m_2 \dot{\vec r_2(t)}^2$

$U_{m2}=m_2 g l_2(1-cos(\phi_2(t)))$

And $L=(T_{m1}+T_{m2})-(U_{m1}+U_{m2})$

Now the problem I have is with the potential energy of the 2nd object:

It's kinetic energy is positive, as a value, and because during it's motion, we have the conversion kinetic energy to potential energy, then the potential energy is positive. But for the potential energy, if we are rigorous, we write:

$U_{m2}=m_2g(-l_2-(l_2cos(\phi_2(t))))$.

So, in short, I am not sure whether my Lagrangian is correct. I am not sure, but perhaps we must have a term of the form $m_1gl_f(t)(1-cos(\phi_1(t)))$. But I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

The value of the potential energy is not important. It may be positive or negative. All that matters is that the gravitational potential energy should be greater at the top and lower at the bottom. Similarly for the elastic PE. Its value doesn’t matter, but it should have a minimum at the equilibrium length.

Comment: But I assume that for the body with weight m1, there are two components of it's total potential energy, the $\frac 1 2 k l_f(t)^2$ part and the $m1 g h$ part, right?

Comment: The elastic PE part is associated with the spring, not the mass. There are three PE terms: one elastic for the spring and two gravitational (one for each mass). I have clarified my answer